# Getting null on Query snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I ma getting a null return on a stream query. The funny thing is that data came through but on processing it to use it in the app it gets lost somewhere.I know i probably made a silly mistake somewhere yet i've been looking at this issue for three days now. Please help.

Here is the stream

```
  Stream <SellerProfile> get sellerProfile {
    return  sellerProfileCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
        .map(yieldSellerProfile);
  }

  SellerProfile yieldSellerProfile(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.data['shopName']);
    return SellerProfile(
      shopName: snapshot.data['shopName'] ?? '',
      phone: snapshot.data['phone']??'',
      credit: snapshot.data['credit'] ?? '',
      posts: snapshot.data['posts'] ?? '',
      sales: snapshot.data['sales'] ?? '',
      avatarUrl: snapshot.data['avatarUrl'] ?? '',
      location:snapshot.data['location'] ?? '',
      rating: snapshot.data['rating'] ?? '',
      joinedDate: snapshot.data['joinedDate'] ?? '',
    );
  }
```

My idea is that after querying the stream sellerProfile i want to map it into a custom model to use it in the app.

As in the code, i print the `snapshot.data['shopName']` before it is processed and i get the output

```
I/flutter ( 1008): Soko
```

which means the data arrives from firestore but as i try to access the data on my frontend i receive a null

Here is the frontend

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<SellerProfile>(

      stream: SellerDatabaseService(uid: user.uid).sellerProfile,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        SellerProfile profile=snapshot.data;
        print(profile);
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: header(context,strTitle: "Profile"),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

and here is the output when i try to print the profile

```
I/flutter ( 1008): null
```

Where am i going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go the issue. I was trying to build the stream with stream builder instead of returning it from a provider.

So i changed this...

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<SellerProfile>(

      stream: SellerDatabaseService(uid: user.uid).sellerProfile,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        SellerProfile profile=snapshot.data;
        print(profile);
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: header(context,strTitle: "Profile"),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(),
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

To this...

```
 return StreamProvider<BuyerProfile>.value(
          value: BuyerDatabaseService(uid: user.uid).buyerProfile,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            BuyerProfile profile=Provider.of<BuyerProfile>(context);
            if(profile!=null){
              return Scaffold(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the snapshot has data yet. Add a check for this with the `hasData` property of the `AsyncSnapshot`:

```dart
return StreamBuilder<SellerProfile>(
  stream: SellerDatabaseService(uid: user.uid).sellerProfile,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
    }
    if(!snapshot.hasData) {//Check if the snapshot actually has data
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    SellerProfile profile=snapshot.data;
    print(profile);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: header(context,strTitle: "Profile"),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(),
    );
  }
);
```

Ideally you should also check if it `hasError` as well, and if you want more granular control over what to show, you could use the `connectionState`.

Comment: But that does not change the issue that the data is not getting to the frontend. Its just a check

Comment: @Bright What do you mean "not getting to the frontend". This is the frontend.

Comment: The data from firestore has been queried but cant be displayed on the Ui rather

Comment: @Bright Yes and you're not checking whether the data is really in the snapshot yet. Not including this check is a **major** issue. There will always be a case where `snapshot.hasData` is `false` and you're not handling it.

Comment: I see your point, whereas my point is, that does not solve the issue still.

Comment: @Bright Have you tried it? What is the error? how is the behavior different from the intended?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218715/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-bright).

Comment: @asbovelw The OP was unable to give enough clear debugging information for me to help them solve their error and they haven't posted an answer themselves so it would seem they haven't solved it.